# Cloudwatch insights query modification

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

```
Current query :
fields  @message
| filter @message like /ABCD/
| stats count(@message)
```

result: @messages
1         55
 now need to add more like a filter in this query like/BCDE/,/EFGH/,/IJKL/.....
the expected result should be like
@ABCD  @BCDE @EFGH @IJKL...
 55     66     77   88.

Can get like this? all the search keywords must be searched in the entire CloudWatch log.

Answer (score 7):

This should work for you:

```
fields  @message
| filter @message like /ABCD|BCDE|EFGH|IJKL/ 
| fields strcontains(@message, "ABCD") as @CONTAINS_ABCD,
         strcontains(@message, "BCDE") as @CONTAINS_BCDE,
         strcontains(@message, "EFGH") as @CONTAINS_EFGH,
         strcontains(@message, "IJKL") as @CONTAINS_IJKL
| stats sum(@CONTAINS_ABCD) as @ABCD, 
        sum(@CONTAINS_BCDE) as @BCDE, 
        sum(@CONTAINS_EFGH) as @EFGH, 
        sum(@CONTAINS_IJKL) as @IJKL
```

Comment: its working fine, need one more suggestion if we dont get an output how to replace the result with zero's?

Comment: How can i implement the query in AWS cloudwatch API ?

Comment: Excellent query for matching partial results and counting them. thanks.